# Download data from JSON using ObjectMapper and Realm

Tags: ios, json, realm

I'm new in swift and I'd like to use some library for downloading and storing data from JSON. I'm using `ObjectMapper` `Realm` and `Alamofire` to do this. I can download the data with `Alamofire` and `ObjectMapper` but when I started to use `Realm` everything went wrong. The problem is when I used an Array in my Model it worked fine, but after I started use Realm I had to use List instead of Array.

Here is my model:

```
class ServiceItem: Object, Mappable {
dynamic var item: [Item]?
//var item = List<Item>()

required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    item <- map["Item"]
}
}

class Item: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id: String?
    dynamic var parentId: String?
    dynamic var userName: String?
    dynamic var userAddress: String?
    dynamic var userMegye: String?
    dynamic var userUtca: String?
    dynamic var userIrsz: String?
    dynamic var userKontakt: String?
    dynamic var userEmail: String?
    dynamic var userPhone: String?
    dynamic var userMobile: String?
    dynamic var userWeb: String?
    dynamic var userDesc: String?
    dynamic var userImage: String?
    dynamic var gpslat: String?
    dynamic var gpslong: String?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id    <- map["id"]
        parentId         <- map["parent_id"]
        userName      <- map["user_name"]
        userAddress       <- map["user_address"]
        userMegye  <- map["user_megye"]
        userUtca  <- map["user_utca"]
        userIrsz     <- map["user_irsz"]
        userEmail  <- map["user_email"]
        userPhone     <- map["user_phone"]
        userMobile  <- map["user_mobile"]
        userWeb     <- map["user_web"]
        userDesc  <- map["user_desc"]
        userImage     <- map["user_image"]
        gpslat  <- map["gpslat"]
        gpslong     <- map["gpslong"]
        userKontakt    <- (map["user_kontakt"])
    }
}
```

And here is my func to download and store data:

```
func downLoadDataFromJSON() {

    let URL = "...."

    let item = Item()

    Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<ServiceItem>) in

        let serviceResponse = response.result.value

        let realm = try! Realm()

        if let allServices = serviceResponse?.item{
            for items in allServices {

                print(items.id!)
                print(items.userName!)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The difference is when I use "Array", the "for" loop is running and I can see my data from JSON, but if I use "List" the code doesn't even step into the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for ObjectMapper cannot just convert to `List` type, You would need a custom transform for that, something like [this](https://github.com/jakenberg/ObjectMapper-Realm). But I was having some problems with it, as in Realm was not saving my model.

So I chose to go with the following method:

Here in, you declare another variable for the ObjectMapper to work but exclude it to be saved by Realm:

```
let backingItem = List<Item>()
var item: [Item] {
    get {
        return backingItem.map { $0 }
    }
    set {
        backingItem.removeAll()
        backingItem.append(objectsIn: newValue)
    }
}
```

and then

```
override public static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["item"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me where do I have to use `ignoredProperties()` method? It should return with the list?

Comment: Anyway if I use this I got this message: `All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber, RLMArray, RLMLinkingObjects, or subclasses of RLMObject.`

Comment: Did you write the ignoredProperties function. That is the function that tells Realm which properties to not store in DB.